# Characters in MySQL insert ID

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-insert-id

Im kind of new to mysql and php so here we go!

At the moment the $inserted_Claim_id returns 1,2,3 etc. but i want it to have my own personal reference number before the numbers; IE; ACL0123

What i have is this;

```
createClaimRef($inserted_Client_ID,$Claim_Type_Code,$Claim_Type_ID);
$inserted_Claim_id=mysql_insert_id();
```

any help would be much obliged,

Regards

Andrew

Comment: `$inserted_Claim_id = "MYREFERENCEHERE" . mysql_insert_id();` But do not use mysql functions because they are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: I will convert it soon just experimenting with a few things -- i have tried what you have said but still coming up as numbers only!